# Finding the command line options a process was launched with

Tags: c++, delphi, winapi, process, process-explorer

I'm trying to find out how to do this, I'm currently using CreateToolHelp32SnapShot to get a list of the running processes and I've got the FilePaths of the executables which are currently running, but I need to be able to find out what command line options were used to start the process.

I know its possible since you can see it on Process Explorer, I tried finding the source code of the old Process Explorer but had no luck :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check if [NtQueryInformationProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684280%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [ReadProcessMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680553%28VS.85%29.aspx) win API calls will do what you need. There is no simple example for that so check the source code here: [Get Process Info with NtQueryInformationProcess](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/GetNtProcessInfo.aspx)

another way for getting this data is throgh WMI, smth like this:

```
SELECT CommandLine FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = ???
```

more info here: [Win32_Process Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Getting the command line of running processes cannot be done in a reliable fashion.  It is very possible for the command line of a running process to be changed by changing the memory which stores those commands.

Raymond Chen did a nice article on this subject recently detailing why it's not reliable.

- http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2009/11/25/9928372.aspx

Comment: Updated link: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091125-00/?p=15923

Answer (score 0):

One possibility that occurs almost immediately would be to inject a thread into the target process (`CreateRemoteThread`), and have that call `GetCommandLine`.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC the command line parameters are stored in the process environment - if you can access it you can read them too.